# Connecting identical nodes in gepi or networkx

Tags: nodes, networkx, connect, gephi

I have two group of nodes in gephi and there nodes that are in both groups. I need to connect the identical nodes. How can I make this in gephi? (or in netwrokx or anything)

I would greatly appreciate if somebody could help me, it's really important for me to do this and I can't find any usable information on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining both network graphs should do it using NetworkX. Make generous use of the add_edges_from() method instead of add_nodes_from() so you don't overwrite existing nodes with the same name from the previous graph.  This should work unless you have a different idea of what "identical" meant to you.  Also if you could, post up code to let us know how this has progressed.